# Is it possible to transfer my questions from other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, migration

I have ~20 questions on Stack Overflow about Isabelle and Coq. Most of them (probably *all* of them) would be better suited here, and were only posted on SO because I had no better SE site to post to.

I wanted to support the beta by transfering some of my questions here. Is this possible?

Comment: @GuyCoder Indeed, those didn't quite answer my question, as I was asking specifically about _migrating_ the questions, and specifically ones of my own authorship (which I imagined would be easier than from different authors). Shame that it isn't possible.

Comment: I am taken aback that this question has been flagged as a duplicate of those two others. The first, "Vote to Migrate suggestion: Stack overflow" is not even a well-formed question to me. The rationale(s) offered in "Can I forward questions here from other SE sites?" are quite different than the specifics for this one. This one refers to migration by the _author_ of a question that would have been posted here had this site existed at the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Migration is only possible for questions that are fewer than 60 days old. If you want to copy questions manually, please first see my answer to the other Meta question on this topic.